# How do I sign up and download CryENGINE?

Tags: cryengine

I cannot sign up for Cryteks CryENGINE, at [this site](https://www.cryengine.com/get-cryengine). When I click on the "sign up and download" button, nothing happens. I would ask this on their forums, but for that, you need an account.

How do I sign up and download CryENGINE?

Comment: I know that when "nothing happens" on the web, I usually switch browser to a more streamlined one (such as Chrome or Explorer/Edge) and it suddenly 'works'.

Comment: Working now, I used edge, never thought that piece of junk would be useful.

Comment: In case you have further problems with your default browser, try to clear the cache. If all else fails, I have no found a means to contact crytek without access to an account (yay)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/lumberyard/ is built off of CryEngine, and I suspect it will deprecate CryEngine.

Comment: After looking at that, that actually seems better, thanks.

Comment: You can also find the Cryengine on github:https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous experience, [the CryENGINE sign up page has its flaws](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129715/servers-are-never-available-to-download-cryengine). In summary of this example, the best solution you have is to try accessing the site from a different web browser.

Further matters of housekeeping may improve your usability:

- [Clear the browsers cache](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic).
- Update your browser to the latest version.
- Update your browsers Java plugin.

If all matters fail, I have since found means to [contact Crytek](http://www.crytek.com/contact) without having an actual account. You can email Crytek in regard to CryENGINE issues at *cryengine@crytek.com*.